# Problem with integral with delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I have a problem with a passage in this integral with a Delta function:

\begin{align}
I=\frac{A\pi}{h^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} dt \delta(\epsilon-a^2t^2-b)
\end{align}
Now i want to use this identity: $\delta(f(t))=\frac{\delta(t-t_0)}{f'(t_0)}$ where $t_0$:$f(t_0)=0$ so that $t_0=\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon-b\sigma}}{a}$

I tried to solve the integral in this way:
\begin{align}
I=\frac{A\pi}{2a^2t_0h^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} dt \delta(t-t_0)=\frac{A\pi}{4a^2t_0h^2}
\end{align}
but is incorrect, the book, after the use of the identity, says that:

$$I=\frac{A\pi}{h^2}\theta(\epsilon-b\sigma)\int_{0}^{+\infty} dt\frac{1}{2a^2t_0}[\delta(t-t_0)+\delta(t+t_0)] $$

I just can't figure out where that theta function and that second delta function came from.

$a$ and $b$ are constants, $\epsilon$ is a variable.

Comment: In the first Equ. $b$ should be $b\sigma$.

Comment: So what if $\epsilon < b\sigma$. Then $t_0$ and, thus, your solution of $I$ would be imaginary (or undefined if you stay within $\mathbb{R}$), which is not the case for the original $I=0$.

Comment: The book answer is rather confusing. It is correct only assuming $a > 0$, in which case it could have just as well kept only the $\delta(t - t_0)$ term. Verify that
$$\int_0^\infty \delta(a^2 t^2 - b) \, dt =
\frac {\theta(b)} {2 |a| \sqrt b},
\quad a b \neq 0$$
(consider why the change of variables formula has an absolute value and a sum over all real roots and why $\int_0^\infty \delta(t - 1) \, dt$ is not taken to be $1/2$).